# Indices and powers of 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, index-notation

To find the value of $x^8$ given $x$, you need three arithmetic operations: $x^2=x\times x$, $x^4$=$x^2 \times x^2$ and $x^8=x^4\times x^4$. To find $x^{15}$, five operations will do: the first three of them are the same; then $(x^{16})=(x^8)\times (x^8)$ and $(x^15)=(x^{16})/x$ . What is the minimum number of operations (multiplications and divisions) will be needed to find the value of $x^{1000}$?

I tried solving this problem logically as follows :

for $(x^8) \Rightarrow 3=3+0$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)->/(x^0) = (x^8)$

for $(x^{15}) => 5=4+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})->/(x^1) = (x^15)$

for $(x^{30}) => 6=5+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})->(x^{32})->/(x^2) = (x^{30})$

for $(x^{61}) => 7=6+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})->(x^{32})->(x^{64})->/(x^3) = (x^{61})$

for $(x^{124}) => 8=7+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})->(x^{32})->(x^{64})->(x^{128})->/(x^4) = (x^{124})$

for $(x^{251}) => 9=8+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})->(x^{32})->(x^{64})->(x^{128})->(x^{256})->/(x^5) = (x^{251})$

for $(x^{506}) => 10=9+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})\rightarrow(x^{32})\rightarrow(x^{64})\rightarrow(x^{128})\rightarrow(x^{256})\rightarrow(x^{512})\rightarrow/(x^6) = (x^{506})$

for $(x^{1017}) => 11=10+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})\rightarrow(x^{32})\rightarrow(x^{64})\rightarrow(x^{128})\rightarrow(x^{256})\rightarrow(x^{512})->(x^{1024})\rightarrow/(x^7) = (x^{1017})$

for $(x^{2048}) => 12=11+1$ operations : $(x^2)\rightarrow(x^4)\rightarrow(x^8)\rightarrow(x^{16})\rightarrow(x^{32})\rightarrow(x^{64})\rightarrow(x^{128})\rightarrow(x^{256})\rightarrow(x^{512})\rightarrow(x^{1024})\rightarrow(x^{2048})/(x^8) = (x^{2048})$

By this approach, I do not get $x^{1000}$.   Please advise.

Comment: in your route to $x^{61}$, why is division by $x^3$ counted as just one operation ? Even if you store the value of $x^2$, don't you need one multiplication to get $x^3$, and then the division, which makes two operations, giving a total of 8 ?

Comment: There's a variation of this called "addition chains" where there are unsolved problems, so this one is probably not easy (in general, that is – it may not be that hard for 1000, I don't know). But I'd advise calculating the first 10 values and then consulting the OEIS.

Comment: The somewhat straightforward approach would be to compute
$$ x^2,x^4,x^8,x^{16},x^{32},x^{64}, x^{128}, x^{256}, x^{512}$$
by repeated squaring (9 operations).
Then multiply
$$ x^{512}x^{256}x^{128}x^{64}x^{32}x^8=x^{1000}$$
(another 5 operations) for a total of $14$ operations.

But you could also compute $x^2, x^4, x^8$, and $x^{10}$ in four operations, then similarly $x^{100}=(x^{10})^{10}$ and $x^{1000}=(x^{100})^{10}$ in eight more operations for a total of $12$ operations. (Still not using divisions). The proof that 11 ops are not enough may be a bit convoluted ...

Comment: Isn't this isomorphic to getting $1000$ using only $1,+,-,*$? Might be easier to think about in this form.

Comment: Thank You @HagenvonEitzen ...   The total of 12 operations, did help to get (x^1000). ...   but, I am confused if the question is trying to presenting some pattern by showing (x^8) and (x^15) operations?

Comment: can I present 12 operations as : (x^2)→(x^4)→(x^8)→(x^16)→(x^32)→(x^64)→(x^128)→(x^256)→(x^512)−>(x^1024)→/(x^16)→/(x^8) = (x^1000)

Comment: Making any progress on my suggestion, Math?

Comment: @GerryMyerson   Thank You very much for the suggestion ...   I have worked out 12 operations as : (x^2)→(x^4)→(x^8)→(x^16)→(x^32)→(x^64)→(x^128)→(x^256)→(x^512)−>(x^1024)→/(x^16)→/(x^8) = (x^1000)   ...   I hope this is accurate.

Comment: I think you'll find your function tabulated at http://oeis.org/A128998 (but only up to $n=87$).